# ESP32 S3 Same code works on Serial1 but NOT on Serial0 for RS485 module

Tags: serial, uart, temperature-sensor, rs485, esp32-s3

I have designed a test board to understand ESP32-S3 working pins. I am using USB interface D+, D- for programing so Serial0 is free to use.

This is my test circuit for testing an RS485 converter. For the test, I am using an MD02 temperature and humidity sensor. Also for the converter I am using [this module](https://www.robotistan.com/rs485-ttl-uart-donusturucu-1)

[image]

This code is not working on Serial0 despite Rx and Tx LEDs are blinking on the RS485 converter.

```
#include <HardwareSerial.h>

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial0.begin(9600, SERIAL_8N2, 44, 43);
  Serial.begin(115200);
}

void loop() {
  Serial0.write("READ");
  delay(3000);
  Serial.print("Temp ve NEM: ");
  while (Serial0.available() > 0) { 
    Serial.print(char(Serial0.read()));
  }
  Serial.println(".");
}
```

This is working

```
#include <HardwareSerial.h>

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial1.begin(9600, SERIAL_8N2, 18, 17);
  Serial.begin(115200);
}

void loop() {    
  Serial1.write("READ");
  delay(3000);
  Serial.print("Temp ve NEM: ");
  while (Serial1.available() > 0) {
    Serial.print(char(Serial1.read()));
  }
  Serial.println(".");
}
```

**What should I do differently for Serial0 and RS485?,** because the 6M NEO GPS module is working properly on Serial0.

Comment: There are RX0 and **TX1** on the PCB. Are these actually the right pins?

Comment: Yes, RX0 and TX1 names comes from arduino nano. But this 44 and 43 pins of esp32 s3. Also same code working with gps modules as i said.

Comment: You might want to use your oscilloscope to look for differences. `"READ"` should be easily detectable, and you can look for the reply. Compare baudrate and UART protocol.